# Display data from a json object array

Tags: json, loops, angular, angular-services

I am unable to loop through a json object array and display all data in separate divs. 
Currently just using some mock data.

Team.servie.ts:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Team } from './team';

@Injectable()
export class TeamService {
    private _url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    constructor(private _http: Http){

    }

    getPost() : Observable<Team[]>{
        return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

    createPost(post: Team){
        return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(post))
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TeamService } from '../team.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'About',
 templateUrl: './about.component.html',
 providers: [TeamService]
  })
export class AboutComponent  implements OnInit{

   data;


   isLoading = true;

        constructor(private _teamService: TeamService){
        /*this._teamService.createPost({userId: 1, title: "a", body: "b"});*/
        }

            ngOnInit(){

                var text = "";
                    var i = 0;

                    this._teamService.getPost()
                .subscribe(post => { 

                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.data = post;
                    console.log(post[0]);
                });
            }
}
```

Team.ts

```
export interface Team{
    userId: number;
    id?: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">Getting data....</div>


<div let displayData of data>

    <p> {{ displayData.id }}</p>

</div>
```

I know I am missing something, but i can't figure out what.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the *ngFor structureal directive like:

```
<div *ngFor="let displayData of data">

    <p> {{ displayData.id }}</p>

</div>
```